# std::variant: Why no viable overloaded '=' error

Tags: c++builder

I try to understand **std::variant** in C++Builder Rad Studio Rio 10.3.1 (CLANG version 5.0). In a console app, I simply have:

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <variant>

 int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
 {
    std::variant<int, float> v;
    v = 12;
    return 0;
 }
```

When I try to compile, it returns an error:

[image]

I am confused because it is an example that I found in several web pages. It is expected to compile without problems. The **12** value should not be candidate for float. However, using the CLANG compiler of Rad Studio it does not compile.

Comment: The code you pasted is fine. Seems like you have `const`-qualified `v` in the code the error message stems from?

Comment: Please create a [mcve] to show us, and copy-paste the error messages (in full and complete) from that example.

Comment: [Can't reproduce](https://wandbox.org/permlink/fbbJLSkbCcntm45Z). Please make sure your MCVE also contains a version of Clang too.

Comment: I can confirm this in 10.3.1, looks like a bug. There is no open bug report on this, so I recommend that you file one yourself.

Comment: This seems to be a bug with Clang 5.0 and 6.0. It seems to be fixed for Clang 7.0 (and higher).

Comment: @StoryTeller: There is a C++Builder tag (I removed the general C++ tag). I guess it is reproducible in C++Builder. That problem arises each time when C++Builder users use the general C++ tag. The Clang compiler and the runtime of C++Builder are sometimes slightly different than general C++. I always advise that people **only** use the C++Builder tag to avoid what happened here: the question was closed by people who don't even use C++Builder.

Comment: @kokokok: Which version? 10.0 Seattle, 10.1Berlin, 10.2 Toyko or 10.3 Rio?

Comment: @RudyVelthuis - It got closed because the first version looked like this https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/55354831/1 - And I already came back after the edit to reopen even before the retagging, so you know, wasn't anything to do c++-builder related bias

Comment: @StoryTeller: I didn't want to offend. I didn't mean anyone had a C++Builder related bias. I merely meant that C++Builder has its own peculiarities (especially due to the forced compatibility with Delphi -- FWIW I would never post a Delphi question with a pascal tag either), and other C++ users don't generally know about them. But the original question doesn't look good, indeed.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis - None taken, or meant. Just felt compelled to comment since you mentioned me explicitly :)

Comment: I can confirm this too. And if you try to compile this with bcc64 (Clang too), you even get 34 errors.